Should specific hardware problem questions be closed as "too localised"?
Should questions about specific hardware problems be close as "too localised"? For example, a question like this:
Help locating bottleneck on new mining rig
Seems to be a quite specific problem. Should we redirect such problems to the forum instead, or try to answer them here?

The important question to ask is: "Is this question likely to ever help any future visitors?". If not, it should be closed as "too localized". I don't know that much about hardware and mining but it seems to me that this question could actually help future visitors. It already has 4 upvotes too so that's an indication that it isn't too localized. 

I don't think this is a good question to ask. On Stack Overflow it is full of questions about very specific snippets of code, which most assuredly won't help anyone besides who is asking... but are allowed anyway.

Questions should be made as generic as possible. Instead of closing, how about suggesting an edit, or editing it yourself, to make it a general question, unrelated to specific hardware (whenever possible)?
Even if the specific hardware details are in the crux of the question, I say it's on topic.
